# iOS: RESTKit RKRequestMethodDELETE with parameters

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20, http-delete

How do I send parameters with `RKRequestMethodDELETE` request.  I need to send `groupId` (INT) and `users` (an array).

Below is the code that I'm using and it's appending it to the URL:

```
https://www.domain.com/g/members?groupId=15&users[][userId]=john.doe
```

Instead I would like to send the request to:

```
https://www.domain.com/g/members
```

and have `groudId` and `users` array as part of the request as parameters.

I need to send

```
{
    [self newObjectManager];
    [self refreshMOC];

    RKEntityMapping *groupMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:kEntityGroup inManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.managedObjectStore];
    groupMapping = [TBSRESTMappingProvider groupGetMapping:groupMapping];

    NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:groupMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodDELETE
                                                                                       pathPattern:kPathPOSTGroupMembers
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodeSet];

    NSArray *stringMembers = [self NSStringMembersFromFriendObjects:members];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.objectManager.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:kRequestMethodDELETE
                                                                               path:kPathPOSTGroupMembers
                                                                         parameters:@{ @"groupId": group.groupId,
                                                                                       @"users" : stringMembers }];

    [self.objectManager.HTTPClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
    operation.managedObjectContext = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
    operation.managedObjectCache = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: What is this additional info? Is it related to a single object? Or you're trying to delete multiple objects? Why aren't you using the object manager DELETE interface?

Comment: The server requires additional info contained in the array to delete multiple objects.  Object manager DELETE interface?  Do you mean: deleteObject:path:parameters:success:failure: method?  Is there a method with object manager to delete multiple object?

Comment: You can try passing an array of objects, or passing it a dictionary containing an array and have either of those encoded to JSON...

Comment: Using RKManagedObjectRequestOperation?  I think that's what I'm doing in the code above, no? `users` is an array.  Can you please provide an example as an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: When you have a minute can you please answe this. I'm stuck!  Thanks.

Comment: You don't use `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` if you use the object manager interface. I haven't tried it before (so I don't know if it encodes the object to JSON), but did you pass an array of objects? By using `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` direct with a request you are skipping all JSON related processing...

Comment: If I use 'POST' instead of 'DELETE' JSON seems to be included in the request.  It's something with 'DELETE'.